# Using select() on listening socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, bind

I want to open a port and wait for incoming connections, however I can't get `select()` to work. I had it working with `poll()` but I need `select()` for portability. What am I doing wrong?

Code for waiting for the connection looks like this (I need to check for interruptions every 200ms):

```
/* Wait for a descriptor */
int wait_for_fd(int fd){
  int waitms = 200;
  struct timeval tv;
  tv.tv_sec = 0;
  tv.tv_usec = waitms * 1000;
  fd_set rfds;
  FD_ZERO(&rfds);
  FD_SET(fd, &rfds);
  int active = 0;
  while(active == 0){
    active = select(fd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    bail_for(active < 0, "select()");
    if(pending_interrupt())
      break;
  }
  return active;
}
```

And then my code to actually open a port and wait for a connection:

```
int open_port(int port){

  // define server socket
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  //creates the listening socket
  int listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bail_for(listenfd < 0, "socket()");
  bail_for(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0, "bind()");
  bail_for(listen(listenfd, 10) < 0, "listen()");

  //each accept() is a new incoming connection
  printf("Waiting for connetion on port %d...\n", port);
  wait_for_fd(listenfd);
  int connfd = accept(listenfd, NULL, NULL);
  bail_for(connfd < 0, "accept()");
  printf("Incoming connection!\n");

  //do not allow additional client connetions
  close(listenfd);
  return connfd;
}
```

However `wait_for_fd()` never returns (due to select always returning 0) even when a client is connecting.

Comment: `select` for portability? Portability to what? PDP-11? `select` is disastrously slow and unless you do some really weird, non-portable and undocumented hacks you'll start crashing and/or overwriting random memory when you have more than X (usually 1024) file descriptors open. `select` is dead and should have been removed from standards at least 10, if not 15 years ago. Please reconsider. Using `select` in new software is like using MD5 in new crypto.

Comment: Windows (mingw-w64) does not have `poll()`.

Comment: @Art portability to POSIX. `poll` isn't much better performance-wise and doesn't support atomically unblocking signals. The 1024 limit is hardly an issue, if you have that many file descriptors you should put POSIX aside for an O(1) alternative, but such alternatives are overkill if you only have a few file descriptors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must be on every iteration:

```
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(fd, &rfds);
```

Because `rfds` is an in/out parameter for `select()`. It actually tells with it which fds were affected.

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to manpage of `select`

> On exit, the sets are modified in place to indicate which file descriptors actually changed status. Each of the three file descriptor sets may be specified as NULL if no file descriptors are to be watched for the corresponding class of events.

This means, that, when you have called select and no file-descriptors have changed, no file-descriptors are set in `rfds`. Therefor you'll have to set them on each iteration

```
while(active == 0){
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);
    active = select(fd+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    bail_for(active < 0, "select()");
    if(pending_interrupt())
      break;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!